# How to enable the windows/linux-like "click to open/reduce windows" on the dock

Tags: windows, dock, ui

There is a really intuitive behavior in windows or linux systems: when I reduce a window, it vanishes to the corresponding "dock" icon. Then, when I click on the program icon, the window shows up.

On OSX, the reduced window goes to the right side of the dock. When I click on the corresponding program icon, nothing happens.

Is there any software that can enable the windows/linux reduce/show behavior ?

### Edit

Additionally, is it possible to reduce the window when I click another time on the application icon ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to check "Minimize windows into application icon" in System Preferences → Dock.

The application will then get minimized into its own Dock icon and clicking it will restore it, exactly as you suggest (although the restore behaviour should also happen even if the icon is minimized into the right hand side of the Dock).

Comment: Thanks for the tip ! Last thing though: is it possible to reduce the window when I click again on the app icon ? (that's the second part of the windows/linux behavior :) )

Comment: @ldiqual No problem. Unfortunately I don't think that's possible currently. The best you can do seems to be to check "Double-click a window's title bar to minimize" in System Preferences -> General - but that's not exactly ideal. Maybe something like [HyperDock](http://hyperdock.bahoom.com/) or [Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/) can do that?